# C++ sqlite3_prepare: "SQL logic error or missing database"

Tags: c++, syntax, parameters, sqlite

This is the SQL code I want to run on my SQLite3 DB:

`INSERT INTO tbl_types VALUES(?, ?);`

But no matter how much I play with `?`s I get the same `"SQL logic error or missing database"` error, while simply replacing the `?`s with custom arbitrary values, runs and I get the record there in my table, and thus I deduce something's wrong with my syntax.

What's the cure?

Comment: Please show the code that does the actual call and parameter binding.

Comment: The code is more than few lines to copy and its in several files. I just tried `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (instead of `sqlite3_prepare`) and it returns `Datatype mismatch` error. Does it tell anything?

Comment: Yes, it tells that you've got errors in your code. Try and create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) if you can't extract the relevant parts from your existing stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must apologize for I found the problem partly by Googling and partly brute force:

1. I was supplying a default **0** argument for an auto increment field, which I replaced with **NULL**, this I found on the web.
2. I was binding my values starting from 0, while the doc says `The leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1` and I was confusing it with the similar clause I read at `column` page.

Thanks for taking your time anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error. But later I have noticed that I have misspelled one of the parameter names.